# Exclude category from fucntion

Tags: categories, exclude

### QUESTION

Hey guys, I have this function and I need to exclude 2 categories: 81 and 82. Can You help? :)

### CODE

```
function has_related_same_cat_posts(){
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);

if ($categories) {
    $category_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $individual_category) 
        $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

    $args=array(
    'category__in' => $category_ids,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page'=> 4, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
    'caller_get_posts'=>1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    
    );

    $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $return = true;
    } else {
        $return = false;
    }
    
}

return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($categories as $individual_category) {        
    if( $individual_category->term_id == 81 || $individual_category->term_id == 82 ) 
        continue;
    $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id; 
}
```

explanation:

the above replaces:

```
foreach($categories as $individual_category) 
        $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
```

i.e. the code jumps over the to be excluded categories.

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code.

Comment: @ialocin explanation added.

Comment: Perfect, you answer was on the low quality queue, I guess it was because of the missing explanation.